# cancel process without using delay task

Tags: extjs

I have the following delay task in the below method:
 exportDataToCSV: function () {

```
var me = this,
    grid = this.option.up('grid');      

var mask = Ext.widget('processingmessagebox', {
    target: grid,
    progressMessage: 'exporting',
    isProcessing: true,
    targetFunctions: {
        ConfirmCancelClick: me.stopExportingData
    }
});
mask.getViewModel().set({ ShowCancelBox: 'block' });
var grdStore = grid.getStore();
var grdProxy = grdStore.getProxy();
exportData = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function () {

        me.printDataToCSV(grid, mask);

});
exportData.delay(2000);
```

},

```
stopExportingData: function () {
    exportData.cancel();
}
```

This is working fine. But, I am  trying to cancel the "exportdata" process without using delay task. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Why can't you use a delayed task? What is the limitation that prevents you from using it?

Answer (score 1):

You kind of can't. Javascript - and thus ExtJS - is single-threaded. If your code is busy doing something, it can't respond to a cancel button.

In order to make a long-running task cancelable - or even just to allow a progress bar to update - it needs to be broken up into a series of steps. These steps need to then be put on the task queue - something that ExtJS's delayed task does for you.

For something like export data to a CSV, a common approach would be to create a task that exports, say, a dozen records, and then puts another task to read the next dozen.

There are certainly other approaches than using DelayedTask in particular, but they all revolve around the underlying `setTimeout` or `setInterval` methods.

Here's an example using a [regular ExtJS task](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.util.TaskRunner.html), and not DelayedTask:

```
var readNextDozenRecords = function(indexToReadFrom) { ... }
var writeDataChunk = function(recordsToWrite) { ... }

var taskConfig = {
  currentIndex: 0,
  interval: 10, // runs every 10ms or so.
  run: function() {
    var nextDataChunk = readNextDozenRecords(currentIndex);
    if (nextDataChunk.length == 0) {
      this.stop(); // 'this' scope is the running task.
      return;
    }
    currentIndex += nextDataChunk.length;
    writeDatakChunk(nextDataChunk);
  }
}

exportData = Ext.TaskManager.newTask(taskConfig);
// The exportData can be manually canceled by calling the `stop` method.
```